# How to divide row count over a specific column in a report

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I have a matrix report of opportunities, and stages group the columns. I need to divide the row count of each stage over the first stage (column), for example, first column / second column, first column / three columns, first column / four columns, etc.

[image]